# When I try to pass a value it is empty in the new activity

Tags: android

I want to pass a double that I get from an editText field to a new activity. It is possible to open the App on my device and to type a number into the editText field. But in the new activity it is only shown as 0.0 .
How do I correct this?

Activity 1

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button weiter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.weiter);
    weiter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText EingabeBreite = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.breite);

            double breite = Double.parseDouble(EingabeBreite.getText().toString());

            Intent rüber = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            rüber.putExtra("next", "breite");
            startActivity(rüber);
```

Activity 2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    TextView ergebnis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    double breite = extras.getDouble("next");


    ergebnis.setText(Double.toString(breite));



    }
```

Comment: The string `"breite"` is not a double.

Comment: @Henry 1 can you tell me how I get "breite" to a double?

Comment: use like this : `rüber.putExtra("next", breite);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the below line

```
rüber.putExtra("next", "breite");
```

as following

```
rüber.putExtra("next", breite);
```

Comment: Yesss. Thank you so so much !